# Google Drive file upload in hybrid apps

Tags: android, ios, google-drive-api

We have a hybrid app where most of the code is handled in Javascript (including logging in via Google Sign In and some uploading to Google Drive). On iOS, we have other Google Drive uploading code, but I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing in Android. I'm trying avoid having the user log into the web portion and then again for Android.

The iOS code that is being used to upload is...

```
let mutableURLRequest           = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")!)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod    = "POST"
let boundaryConstant            = generateBoundaryString()
let contentType                 = "multipart/related; boundary="+boundaryConstant

// Set the headers
mutableURLRequest.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
mutableURLRequest.addValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
mutableURLRequest.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
mutableURLRequest.addValue("\(requestData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

// create upload data to send
let uploadData = NSMutableData()
uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

let date        = NSDate()
let calendar    = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components  = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: date)
let fileName    = "\(components.year)-\(components.month)-\(components.day).\(ext)"

// Add parameters
let params = [
    "name":             fileName,
    "mimeType":         mimeType,
    "parents":          ["\(slnFldrId)"],
    "convert":          true
]

// Add the file meta data (JSON format)
uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData("\(getJsonString(params))\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

// Add the file
uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData(requestData)
uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = uploadData

let configuration   = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session         = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
let task            = session.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(mutableURLRequest)
task.resume()
```

...So it's just using the REST endpoint and works nicely. For Android, I've tried using the HttpClient with HttpPost and setting headers, etc., but I always get a 400 error (Bad request).

```
String ext      = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
String mimeType = mimeTypeFromTypeId(typeId);
String boundary = getBoundary();
String tail     = "\r\n-"+ boundary +"--\r\n";

HttpParams httpParams   = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
HttpClient httpClient   = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost httpPost       = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ Common.accessToken);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length", ""+ file.length());

String json = "{\"name\":\"Android upload."+ ext +"\",\"mimeType\":\""+ mimeType +"\",\"parents\":[\""+ Common.slnFldrId +"\"],\"convert\":true}";

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
entityBuilder.setCharset(MIME.UTF8_CHARSET);
entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entityBuilder.addTextBody("", json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("", file, ContentType.create(mimeType), "Android upload."+ ext);

httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart-related; boundary="+ boundary);
try
{
    return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}
catch(ConnectTimeoutException e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

...I think the headers are causing the bad request error. Even though I'm setting the Content-Type header to multipart/related, it is always converted to multipart/form-data (I think by the MultipartEntityBuilder).

As far as I can tell, the Google Client libraries all require an authorization process (in that I can't set the accessToken that I already have from the web login into them), which is why I'm not using them.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is based off the article at http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

Here is the code with some changes to make it work correctly with the Google Drive API.

```
URL url                         = null;
HttpURLConnection connection    = null;
try
{
    // Set up some constants and "global" variables
    String BOUNDARY             = getBoundary();
    String LINE_FEED            = "\r\n";
    String UTF8                 = "UTF-8";

    String fileName = file.getName();
    String ext      = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    String mimeType = mimeTypeFromTypeId(typeId);

    // Use the calendar to give the file a name
    Calendar cal    = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cYear       = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);//calender year starts from 1900 so you must add 1900 to the value recevie.i.e., 1990+112 = 2012
    int cMonth      = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);//this is april so you will receive  3 instead of 4.
    int cDay        = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int cHour       = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int cMin        = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int cSec        = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    String name     = cYear +"-"+ cMonth +"-"+ cDay +"-"+ cHour +"-"+ cMin +"-"+ cSec +"."+ ext;

    // JSON meta-data part
    String json         = "{\"name\":\""+ name +"\",\"mimeType\":\""+ mimeType +"\",\"parents\":[\""+ Common.slnFldrId +"\"],\"convert\":true}";
    String META_PART1   = "--"+ BOUNDARY + LINE_FEED
            + "Content-Type: application/json; charset="+ UTF8 + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED
            + json + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED;

    // File meta-data part
    String META_PART2   = "--"+ BOUNDARY + LINE_FEED
            + "Content-Type: "+ mimeType + LINE_FEED + LINE_FEED;

    // Tail
    String TAIL         = LINE_FEED +"--"+ BOUNDARY +"--";

    long contentLength  = META_PART1.length() + META_PART2.length() + file.length() + TAIL.length();

    // Set up the HttpUrlConnection
    url         = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
    connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+ Common.accessToken);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary="+ BOUNDARY);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ contentLength);
    connection.connect();

    // Get the connection's output stream
    OutputStream outputStream    = connection.getOutputStream();

    // Write the META_PART1 (JSON) and flush
    outputStream.write(META_PART1.getBytes(UTF8));
    outputStream.flush();

    // Write the META_PART2 (file's contentType) and flush
    outputStream.write(META_PART2.getBytes(UTF8));
    outputStream.flush();

    // Write the FILE
    int totalRead   = 0;
    int bytesRead   = -1;
    byte[] buffer   = new byte[4096];
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        outputStream.flush();
        totalRead      += bytesRead;
        float progress  = totalRead / (float)contentLength;
        delegate.onUploadProgress(progress);
    }
    // Flush the last of the file data and close the inputStream
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    // Flush the TAIL and close the outputStream
    outputStream.write(TAIL.getBytes(UTF8));
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    // Get the server response
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == HTTP_SUCCESS)
    {
        BufferedReader reader   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line             = "";
        StringBuilder builder   = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        // Send the completed message to the delegate
        delegate.onUploadComplete(builder.toString(), typeId);
    }
    else
    {
        // Send the error message to the delegate
        delegate.onUploadError(file);
    }
}catch(IOException e)
{
    // Send the error message to the delegate
    delegate.onUploadError(file);
}finally
{
    if(connection != null)
    {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```